# SQL Server Join working, linq is not

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

This linq statement will not work:

```
var other = from g in picks
            join sp in _playersContext.SportPlayers
                    on g.SportPlayerID equals sp.ID
            select g;
```

This T-SQL statement returns data:

```
SELECT * 
FROM draftpick dp
JOIN FF2018AllSportsPlayers.dbo.SportPlayer sp ON dp.SportPlayerID = sp.ID
WHERE dp.DraftTeamManagerID = 7
```

I have been trying to figure out why for the last 45 minutes or so...

An error message is:

> ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: entityType
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Utilities.Check.NotNull(T value, string parameterName)

Comment: A complicating factor is that you're joining queries from two different context, (which is only clear from seeing your answer, but should have been visible in your question). EF can't compose one SQL statement from DbSets originating in different contexts.

Answer (score 0):

Casting both collections to lists first worked, not sure why, maybe it has something to do with Asynchronous tasks?

```
var picks = await _context.DraftPicks.Where(p => p.DraftTeamManagerID == id).ToListAsync();
var players = await _playersContext.SportPlayers.ToListAsync();
```